# Reference Request: Louis B. Rall, George F. Corliss: An Introduction to Automatic Differentiation SIAM, 1996

Tags: reference-request, research

Automatic Differentiation (*AD*) seems like the swiss army knife of quickly solving optimization problems (involving partial derivatives) on a computer. I was looking at the website dedicated to *AD*. It [lists](https://www.autodiff.org/?module=Introduction&submenu=Surveys) an early paper

> Louis B. Rall, George F. Corliss: An Introduction to Automatic Differentiation SIAM, 1996

I am not able to find this paper in its entirety. The first two pages appear to be available at this website: http://dennisdarland.com/my_sw_projects/intro_auto_2pages.pdf.

Can you help find a copy of this paper (hopefully not behind a paywall)?

Comment: According to your link it's part of [these](https://www.amazon.com/Computational-Differentiation-Applications-Proceedings-Mathematics/dp/0898713854) proceedings. Available for borrowing on the Internet Archive. However, it does not seem to be available on SIAM's site.

Comment: I can now understand the difficulty of such a question. I found the paper. Thanks to @Jean-ClaudeArbaut. Should we close this question?

Comment: Not necessarily. You may also answer your own question. Where did you finally find the paper?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Jean-Claude Arbaut suggested that I answer my own question.

This paper is available in its entirety as the Chapter 1 of *Computational Differentiation: Techniques, Applications, and Tools*: Proceedings of the 2nd International Workshop on Computational Differentiation, Santa Fe, New Mexico, February 12-14, 1996.

It is available for reading on archive.org [here](https://archive.org/details/computationaldif0000unse_w0k7/page/n9/mode/2up?view=theater).

The paper is one of the best introductions to the *automatic differentiation* technique.